# Json Data from FrontEnd not being Inserted to the database Via the backend using Knockout and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am working on a project where I save some stuff from the localstorage into my database using Knockout and MVC. The issue i am having is that the data i specify in the controller that i need to also send to the back end gets inserted but the data i am pulling from the front end does not get inserted. 
Here is my frontend api.js :

```
 function Save(data){
        // var promise = appsecurity.postApiCall(root+'/Save', ko.toJSON(data));
        return appsecurity.putApiCall(root+'/Save', ko.toJSON(data));
    }
```

The projectfile.js

```
         self.changeButtonText = function(){
         self.ProcurementbuttonText(!self.ProcurementbuttonText())
         self.ElementData = ko.observable(localStorage.getItem('ElementDataWidget'));
         self.scorecardIDLocalStorage = ko.observable(localStorage.getItem('scorecardId'));
         self.AllData = ko.observableArray([]);
         self.AllData.push(self.scorecardIDLocalStorage,self.ElementData);

         var JSONData = ko.toJSON(self.AllData);
         PreferentialProcurementDashboardApi.Save(JSONData);
         console.log((JSONData));


        }
```

So as you can see i am logging my `JSONData` to make sure i do get the data from the local storage, so that does show in my console. Here is my backend Code

Controller.cs:

```
 [HttpPut]
    [Route("Save")]
    [ValidateModel]
    //[TrackActivity(section: "Dashboard", actionType: UserActivityActionType.Update, actionDescription: "Create/Update dashboard View Entry")]

    public IHttpActionResult Save(DashboardConfigEditViewModel dashboardConfigEditViewModel)
    {
        //var databaseDetails = _prefentialDashboardConfigService.GetById(dashboardConfigEditViewModel.DashboardId);
        //if (databaseDetails != null)
        //{
        //    return AccessDenied();
        //}

        //int id = SaveDashboardConfigEditViewModel(dashboardConfigEditViewModel);
        //return Ok(id);

        dashboardConfigEditViewModel.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        dashboardConfigEditViewModel.UserId = this.GetUserId();
        _prefentialDashboardConfigService.Create(PreferentialProcurmentConfigViewModelMapper.MapToDomain(dashboardConfigEditViewModel));
        return Ok();
    }
```

My Mapper.cs:

```
 public static PrefentialDashboardConfig MapToDomain(DashboardConfigEditViewModel dashboardconfigeditviewmodel)
    {
        var config = new PrefentialDashboardConfig();
        config.DashboardId = dashboardconfigeditviewmodel.DashboardId;
        config.ScorecardId = dashboardconfigeditviewmodel.ScorecardId;
        config.UserId = dashboardconfigeditviewmodel.UserId;
        config.DateCreate = dashboardconfigeditviewmodel.DateCreated;
        config.DashboardConfig = dashboardconfigeditviewmodel.DashboardConfig;

        return config;
    }
```

My Dto.cs:

```
 public class DashboardConfigEditViewModel
{

    //public DashboardConfigEditViewModel()
    //{

    //}

    public int DashboardId { get; set; }

    public Guid ScorecardId { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public string DashboardConfig { get; set; }

}
```

and this is the fields in my database:

```
Create Table [data].PrefentialDashboardConfig(
DashboardId int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
ScorecardId uniqueidentifier,
UserId uniqueidentifier,
DateCreate DateTime,
DashboardConfig varchar(255)

)
```

Now if you look at my controller i set the date and userID in the backend, that gets inserted into my database but the scorecardID and the config i get from the front end, that does not get parsed all the way through to my backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property name in the JSON(which we are sending to the server) should match with the property name of the MVC viewmodel class(Parameter of the Save ActionResult method).

**Option 1:**
If you are using [ko.toJSON](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html) method then you should use your model like this below;

```js
var dashboardConfigEditViewModel = {
        ScorecardId:ko.observable(localStorage.getItem('scorecardId')),
        DashboardConfig:ko.observable(localStorage.getItem('ElementDataWidget'))
};

var JSONData = ko.toJSON(dashboardConfigEditViewModel);
PreferentialProcurementDashboardApi.Save(JSONData);
```

**Option 2:**
If you dont want to use [ko.toJSON](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html) method.You can use the below option.

```js
var dashboardConfigEditViewModel = {
        'ScorecardId':ko.observable(localStorage.getItem('scorecardId'))(),
        'DashboardConfig':ko.observable(localStorage.getItem('ElementDataWidget'))()
};


PreferentialProcurementDashboardApi.Save(dashboardConfigEditViewModel);
```

Note: Make sure you are using JSON.stringify() to convert the JSON into string before sending to the server.